# File/module structure in Python

Tags: python, module, package

So I'm just getting started with Python, and currently working my way through http://diveintopython3.ep.io/.  The code examples are nice, but the vast majority of them are little four-line snippets, and I want to see a little more of the big picture.

As I understand it--and correct me if I'm wrong--each '.py' file becomes a "module", and a group of modules in a directory becomes a "package" (at least, it does if I create a `__init__.py` file in that directory).  What is it if I don't have a `__init__.py` file?

So what does each "module" file look like?  Do I generally define only one class in the file?  Does anything else go in that file besides the class definition and maybe a handful of `import` commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is it if I don't have a
>   `__init__.py` file?

It's just a folder.

> Do I generally define only one class
>   in the file?

It depends. Not necessarily.

> Does anything else go in that file
>   besides the class definition and maybe
>   a handful of import commands?

You can put anything you want. Anything that's valid python at least.

Comment: Why? You think it's inconceivable to have a module that's just a single class?

Comment: I have quite a few modules that don't define classes at all. I have others that define some related classes (and still don't exceed 100, 150 lines). Python is not Java - classes aren't obligatory, so you don't use them when there are better options (of course same applies for everything else).

Comment: @Falmarri : no it just because from the OP answer it seem that he is projecting java design on python so i was thinking that you can just tell , that it's __not necessary__ in python saying __it depends__ seem to me like if you're telling him __you can program in python like Java__  well just sentence syntax no big deal well never mind :)

Comment: So, I could make a module `bob` that's just a series of functions.  To use `bob` somewhere else, I `import bob` and then access those functions as `bob.func_one()`, `bob.func_two()` etc.?  Or do I not need the `bob.` preceding the function names?

Comment: If you do a `import bob`, then you need to need to call each function like the way you mentioned it: `bob.func_one()`, etc. If you do a : `from bob import func_one`, this imports *only* `func_one` from `bob` and you call it directly: `func_one()` without the `bob` prefix.

Comment: @keith: Correct. You can avoid the namespace prefix if you explicitly pull some things into the current namespace (`from bob import func_one, func_two`). You *could* also do `from bob import *`, but this is [highly discouraged](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import).

Comment: Ah, that helps a lot.  I didn't realize that functional distinction between a full and partial import.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but it is always worth looking at the standard library to see how they use `__init__.py` in packages like `sqlite3` vs. modules like `SimpleHTTPServer`

Answer (score 0):

Falmarri answers it pretty well, but just to add:

`__init__.py` can be an empty file (and is usually is), but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) variable.

Comment: Or you can put your entire code in `__init__`. Or put the code that you want to expose.

Comment: I've also seen (and I like it, as a library user) `from pkg.subpkg import some, commonly, used, stuff` so `import pkg` already gives you most things you need.